# $E((\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)^2)$ for $X_k$ being the indicator random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X_k$ be some indicator random variable such that $E(X_k) = p$. I'd like to calculate

$$E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^2\right]$$

Is there an easy way to rewrite the sum and use the linearity of the expected value here? I thought about using something like the Multinomial Theorem, but I'm sure that there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: by linearity, $\dots=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E[X_i X_j]$

Comment: Are they independent or at least uncorrelated?

Comment: Hmm, okay. So if $X_i = X_j = 1$, then this would be the same as calculating $E[X_iX_i] = E[X_i] = p.$ But what if $X_i \neq X_j$? Can the sum be calculated further?

Comment: To specify further: $X_k$ is the random variable such that a die shows a $6$ in the k-th run, so yeah, they should be independet as long as $i \neq j$.

Comment: No -- then $E[X_iX_i]=E[X_i^2]$, which probably will not be $p$. If $i\neq j$, you can solve for $E[X_iX_j]$ easily if your variables are independent or uncorrelated, as mentioned by previous commenter...

Comment: And how would I include the case that $i = j$ then?

Comment: treat them separately: $\dots=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i\neq j} E[X_iX_j]$. Do you know how to compute $E[XY]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Sure, that's just $E[X]E[Y]$ then.

Comment: Nice, sounds like you're on your way

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got it now!